# Trying to use table to achieve CSS responsiveness but not working

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to make the following page responsive. But when I hit 550px width I got the following result. If I go further down the resolution all my stuff will be slanted to the left except for the footer. I am a beginner trying to learn responsive design. I really appreciate all the help I can get. If you can provide a bit of explanation it will be great. All help is deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/hansheung/Lhyk3s86/1/

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">

<title>Benefits</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans'

    }

    p,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4 {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    html {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table {
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 0;
    }
    /* ----------- responsivity ----------- */

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        /*------ top header ------ */
        .main-header {
            font-size: 20px !important;
        }
        .main-section-header {
            font-size: 28px !important;
        }
        .show {
            display: block !important;
        }
        .hide {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .align-center {
            text-align: center !important;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .align-left {
            text-align: left !important;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .no-bg {
            background: none !important;
        }
        /*----- main image -------*/
        .main-image img {
            width: 640px !important;
            height: auto !important;
        }
        /*-------- container --------*/
        .container600 {
            width: 460px !important;
        }

        /*-------- secions ----------*/
        /* .section-img img {
            width: 640px !important;
            height: auto !important;
        } */
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        /*------ top header ------ */
        .main-header {
            font-size: 18px !important;
        }
        .main-section-header {
            font-size: 26px !important;
        }
        /*-------- container --------*/
        .container600 {
            width: 400px !important;
        }   
        /*-------- secions ----------*/
        /* .section-img img {
            width: 600px !important;
            height: auto !important;
        } */
    }

    .responsive{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: Kollektif Regular;
        src: url(http://www.talent-trust.com/public-html/fonts/Kollektif.woff);
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Kollektif Bold;
        src: url(http://www.talent-trust.com/public-html/fonts/Kollektif-Bold.woff);
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Kollektif Italic;
        src: url(http://www.talent-trust.com/public-html/fonts/Kollektif-Italic.woff);
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Kollektik BoldItalic;
        src: url(http://www.talent-trust.com/public-html/fonts/Kollektif-BoldItalic.woff);
    }

    .text{
        color: #2d2a26; 
        font-size: 16px; 
        line-height: 28px;
        text-align: justify;
    }

    .singleLine{
        line-height:16px;
    }

    .doubleLine{
        line-height:40px;
    }

    .subtitle{
        font-size: 20px;
        color:#FF7F30;
    }

    .text-color{
        color: #ffffff; 
        font-size: 14px; 
        line-height: 23px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">    
<!-- header -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <table align="center" width="600" class="container600">
                <tr>
                    <td height="10" >&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" align="center" width="600"  class="container600">
                            <tr>
                                <td  class="section-img">
                                    <a href="http://www.talent-trust.com" ><img src="http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/j19-ttc_header.png" width="640"/></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- end header -->
<!-- big banner section -->
<table width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#ffffff url(http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/j19-ttc_banner.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size:cover;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;padding-top:150px;padding-bottom:150px">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--end banner-->
<table border="0" align="center" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container600">
    <tr>
        <td style="line-height: 50px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>                    
    <tr>
        <td align="justified" style="color: #053D56; font-size: 40px; font-family: Kollektif; line-height: 28px;">
            <p>Member Benefits</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="doubleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="text">
            At TTc, we aim to give missionaries the security, physical health, mental health, and wellness support and resources that they need to excel in their calling and stay in the field longer.
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td class="doubleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" width="70%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ff7f30">
                <tr>
                    <td height="2" style="font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<!-- 2 Column Blog Layout-->
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container600">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="50%" align="left" cellpadding="80px" cellspacing="0" class="container600">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-center">
                                    <div>
                                        <p style="color: #053D56; font-size: 30px; font-family:  Kollektif; line-height: 28px;">Keeping your costs down</p>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text">We know cost is a big deal, so we provide multiple ways to keep costs down:</p>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text">
                                            <a href="http://www.talent-trust.com/benefits/ncb.html" class="subtitle" target="blank">No Claims Bonus</a>&nbsp;– We reward our members for staying healthy, which helps us to keep our premiums down. See how you can save up to 50% of your premium. <a href="http://www.talent-trust.com/benefits/ncb.html" target="blank" >Read more…</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table width="50%" align="right" cellpadding="80px" cellspacing="0" class="container600">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-center">
                                    <div >
                                        <p style="color: #053D56; font-size: 30px; font-family:  Kollektif; line-height: 28px;">Tailored Services help you THRIVE Long-Term</p>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text">We look at what services and technology we can offer that will help our members to stay in the field longer.</p>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="text">
                                            <a href="http://www.talent-trust.com/benefits/vhealth.html" class="subtitle" target="blank">vHealth</a>&nbsp;– a 24/7 service that connects you to a European based family doctor from anywhere in the world for free. Using an app on your phone, you can video call or have a vHealth doctor visit whenever and wherever you need it.  <a href="http://www.talent-trust.com/benefits/vhealth.html" target="blank"  >Read more…</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="50" style="font-size: 50px; line-height: 50px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<!-- end section -->


    <tr>
        <td class="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="singleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="singleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="singleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="singleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="singleLine">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="50" style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


</table>
<!-- end section -->
<!-- contact section -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#053D66">
    <tr>
        <td height="40" style="font-size: 40px; line-height: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ff7f30">
                <tr>
                    <!-- <td height="2" style="font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px;">&nbsp;</td> -->
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <table  align="center" width="700"  class="container600">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table  width="300" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container600">
                            <tr>
                                <!-- logo -->
                                <td align="right" class="align-center">
                                    <a href="http://www.talent-trust.com" ><img width="200" border="0" style="display: block; width: 200px;" src="http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/j19-logo_footer.png" alt="" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:right;" class="align-left"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ttcinsurance" target="blank" style="color:#F1F1F1;text-decoration:none;"><img width="24" height="24" src="http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/j19-fb_icon.png" ></a></td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        <table width="2" align="left" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="container600">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="hide" width="2" height="25"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table width="250" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="container600">

                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="text-color">
                                        Email us: <a href="" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;">abc@hotmail.com</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td height="15" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #ffffff;">Tel: +604-899-8945</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="33" style="font-size: 33px; line-height: 33px;"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-left p1"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCG6CJHqgnZN7HbX5NWqEhXg" target="blank"><img width=24 height=24 src="http://www.talent-trust.com/documents/img/j19-youtube_icon.png" ></a></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="60">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<!-- end section -->
```

[image: at 550px]

[image: slanted to the left]

Comment: I tried running your code and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Don't use tables, use semantic correct HTML.

Comment: @RishabhdevTyagi it is not when you run it at 550px width and lower